# My Indian passport is damaged. How can I apply for a new one?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, india, applications, damaged-passports

Damaged Indian passport. To apply for a new passport what should be done?

Comment: Any reason you think it matters, and why you can't just do the normal process?

Comment: You still have that page?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make much difference if the name, photo and passport number are still readable - see the following from the [Embassy of India](http://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports):

> Damaged passport is classified further based on the extent of damage,
>   i.e.:
>
> - Damaged Passport - Passport number is readable, name is legible and photo is intact
> - Damaged beyond recognition
>
> To apply for duplicate passport in case of lost or damaged passport,
>   you need to apply for "Re-issue" of passport.

To apply for a re-issue of a passport, like you'll need to - you follow the same steps as any person getting a new passport.  PassportIndia.gov.in has [the application page with instructions](http://www.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/procEFormSub) - note that:

> If you ever held a passport in the past, no matter how much long back
>   or at what age, you should choose the Re-Issue category only.

Comment: Is it really a reissue?  I would infer that reissue applies only in thecar of a valid damaged passport, not an expired one.

Comment: @phoog the final sentence would seem to indicate expired passports too, damaged or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Having a damaged passport does not preclude you from renewing or obtaining a new one.

But because your passport expired so long ago, you might check to see if you have to go through the original documentation process again or simply follow renewal procedures.