# Consequences of accidentally holding onto two Indian passports simultaneously?

Tags: passports, legal, indian-citizens

Before marking this as a duplicate, please note:- I have already seen [Two passport of the same person in India](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/17194/38275) and the discussion there does not answer my query. That question is about a error in the passport department side and hence easily corrected by them, but in my case it is my/my family's mistake and I would like to know the consequences of that. Please read below.

When I went to the PSK Chennai for renewal of my passport (P1) which was about to expire in less than a year from now, I was shocked to learn that I have another passport (P2) issued under my name in RPO Lucknow almost 18 years ago (ie. during my college time). As I do not have any recollection of the exact events (probably due to my Vitamin D/calcium deficiency ?!) and since my father has unfortunately expired 9 years ago, I dont have the exact account of the events that has led to this situation. But I can try to explain to the best of my knowledge why I am in this situation based on the events from my memory. As I was only 18/19 years old at the time these events happened, I was simply signing where my father asked me to sign without understanding much about what was happening. So, in the write up below I am going to be implying that my beloved father did most of the things !

First, my Father (and I) had applied for Passport P1 for me in RPO Chennai (my place of residence). But we did not know about the status of our application for more than 6 months. Assuming that the application had got rejected, and anxious that I need a passport to pursue my higher studies, my father who has not had any formal school education of any sort, must have been instructed by some travel agent to apply for a passport (P2) near my place of study. 
At the end, Both passports P1 and P2 got delivered. 
My Father must have been aware that one should not USE two passports and hence with this good intention he must not have informed me about the existence of P2 and put P2 away somewhere safe.
He must not have been aware that not only should one not USE two passports, one should NOT even POSSESS two passports.

Though I was aware that it is not correct for a citizen of India to hold two passports, I was NOT aware of the existence of two passports under my name. Only last week, while applying for renewal of passport I learned that there is P2 issued to my name in RPO Lucknow. Guided by the Assistant Passport Officer and the Granting Officer in PSK to sincerely search for P2 at home and surrender it, I did an extensive search of my father's belongings and found it (!!!) along with my father's spiritual books (which had been untouched since the expiry of my father).

- Will this affect the renewal of my primary passport P1, AFTER I surrender P2?
- Will there be any mention of this in my passport P1 (ie a black mark) potentially affecting my future travels ?

Comment: After posting this qn, When I visited the PSK with the two passports they told me that they are fwding my file to RPO, Chennai and asked me to go there. I will be visiting them next week. Will keep you updated.

Comment: Keep us posted!

Comment: Visited the RPO Chennai who thoroughly inspected my explanation and the case and my two passports. They have said that they will be imposing a penalty of Rs 5000 for suppressing the information about P1 when I applied for P2. They said that is how they can treat this case as me or whoever represented me (my father) did not mention about the prev application at the time of applying P2 and there is no way to prove that we are innocent. I can understand their position and am ok with their decision.

Comment: I hope they will be renewing P1 after imposing the fine for P2 and revoking P2. I have been asked to come back after 2 weeks. Still am not sure what are all the bad consequences of having a Passport Revoked. One thing is for sure that whenever I apply for renewal of my passport, I will be treated "special" as I will be saying yes to the qn: "Have you ever had any of your passports revoked/impounded" ! :-(

Comment: Visisted the RPO yday. They took P2 and started the renewal process (pre police verification eventhough there is no change in address/any other detail) for P1. It is not clear to me what is the status of P2. They didnt give any acknowledgement for taking it. I dont know if it is revoked or impounded or simply cancelled. Let me wait for P1 to get renewed then I will file an RTI to know the exact status of P2,

Comment: @vendhan any chance you have new information and could post an answer with what happened in your case? That would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @mts This issue is resolved.I got P1 renewed and even used it for couple of travels abroad without anyone giving me extra trouble. So, looks like there is no blackmark against me. Also, I filed an RTI and got to know the status of P2 is "Revoked". One bad thing is , I now have to say YES to the qn of "Has your passport ever been revoked/cancelled" question that we get asked during Passport Renewal.

Comment: @vendhan thanks a lot for coming back with your feedback. This knowledge might be useful for other travelers so please consider writing it up as an answer (instead of only on comments, which often gets overlooked). If you do not find the time in the next days, another user (or me, haha) might do so, but you are most qualified to do so and you deserve the site rep that the answerer would get the most. Good travels :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel. It is about the laws of a specific country concerning what citizens of said country may or may not do or have. The only thing connecting this to travelling is the word *passport.*

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open, as it is all about passports and passports are all about travel. It is also answerable, only a good soul needs to move the content from comments to an answer. We also have many similar questions about applying for or renewing passports, e.g. [My Indian passport is damaged. How can I apply for a new one?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/60179/32134)

Comment: Following the meta-discussion, I retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will this affect the renewal of my primary passport P1, AFTER I surrender P2?

No. It won't affect it. Only after the surrender of P2 will P1 be considered for renewal.

> Will there be any mention of this in my passport P1 (ie a black mark) potentially affecting my future travels ?

There aren't any publicly visible mentions of this incident in P1 or the new passport obtained after renewing P1. And there was no trouble going abroad using the new passport. Having traveled to China twice, I must say Chinese immigration is not very easy. They were very strict, which I suspect is becuase our Indian passport officials might have made some note of the revocation of P2 in their records, which definitely makes sense.